# Merging 3 lines in one with normal spacing between words in notepad++

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++

I have an output of three lines that I want to merge in one line in notepad++ and be able to copy and paste it in excel in one cell (of course the cell will be stretched). Ctrl + J normally does this but I don't want to press ctrl + J 4000 times.

For example
my file is like this

```
2. Zea mays uncharacterized LOC100192625 (LOC100192625), mRNA
640 bp linear mRNA 
NM_001137839.1 GI:212721527
```

and I need it to be as follows:

```
2. Zea mays uncharacterized LOC100192625 (LOC100192625), mRNA 640 bp linear mRNA NM_001137839.1 GI:21272152
```

I looked at other examples online where a similar question was answered but it introduced tabs in the line  which when I pasted in excel resulted in one line to be separated into three cells within the same row. I don't want that I need the 3 lines in notepad++ to merged into one line and for that one line to be pasted in one cell in excel please and not be separated in cells.

Could anyone help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I merge every 3 lines?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^(.*)(?:\r?\n?|$)(.*)(?:\r?\n?|$)(.*)$`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1 \2 \3`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  <kbd>[image]</kbd>

**Before**:

```
2. Zea mays uncharacterized LOC100192625 (LOC100192625), mRNA
640 bp linear mRNA
NM_001137839.1 GI:212721527
2. Zea mays uncharacterized LOC100192625 (LOC100192625), mRNA
640 bp linear mRNA
NM_001137839.1 GI:212721527
2. Zea mays uncharacterized LOC100192625 (LOC100192625), mRNA
640 bp linear mRNA
NM_001137839.1 GI:212721527
```

**After**:

```
2. Zea mays uncharacterized LOC100192625 (LOC100192625), mRNA 640 bp linear mRNA NM_001137839.1 GI:212721527
2. Zea mays uncharacterized LOC100192625 (LOC100192625), mRNA 640 bp linear mRNA NM_001137839.1 GI:212721527
2. Zea mays uncharacterized LOC100192625 (LOC100192625), mRNA 640 bp linear mRNA NM_001137839.1 GI:212721527
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)